# Android application with gps service blocks the device until restarted

Tags: android, gps

I have a very strange issue about GPS on Android. I have an application that is using com.google.android.gms.location.LocationClient and requesting for locationUpdate each 15 seconds. It is hosted in a background service and is tracking the user's location. Works perfect almost all the time, the problem appears if the phone is in a place where there are not any location providers available(GPS, Wi-Fi, Cell..) for a long time(for example in a basement, garage..). After leaving that place and receiving a new location the whole device blocks and needs hard restart(removing battery) to continue working.. Have you seen this kind of behaviour and do you know a fix about it ?

```
startService(new Intent(this, GPSService.class));
```

and this is the service:

```
public class GPSService extends Service implements LocationListener,
    ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener {

private LocationClient locationclient;
private LocationRequest locationrequest;

private void InitGpsService() {
    if (locationclient != null && locationclient.isConnected()) {
        return;
    }
    int resp = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (resp == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        locationclient = new LocationClient(this, this, this);
        locationclient.connect();

        Log.d("Messangero", "Location Client Connect");

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Google Play Service Error " + resp,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

// Binder given to clients
private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();

public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
    GPSService getService() {
        // Return this instance of LocalService so clients can call public
        // methods
        return GPSService.this;
    }
}

public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return mBinder;
}

public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    InitGpsService();
};

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    super.onStart(intent, startId);

};

public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (locationclient != null && locationclient.isConnected()) {
        locationclient.removeLocationUpdates(this);
        locationclient.disconnect();
    }
}

public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    PreferencesUtil.LoadSettings(this);

    locationrequest = new LocationRequest();
    locationrequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    locationrequest.setInterval(PreferencesUtil.GPSSyncPeriod);
    locationclient.requestLocationUpdates(locationrequest, this);
}

public void onDisconnected() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (locationclient != null && locationclient.isConnected())
        locationclient.removeLocationUpdates(this);

}

public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Thread thr = new Thread(new LocationUpdateThread(GPSService.this,
            location));
    thr.start();
}
}
```

Comment: seems weird... when you say "background service" what exactly have you used?

Comment: The problem is that it is not the application that crashes... the whole phone blocks until restart

Answer (score 0):

A service RUNS in the main thread!!!! This is why it's freezing UI.

> Caution: A service runs in the main thread of its hosting process—the service does not create its own thread and does not run in a separate process (unless you specify otherwise). This means that, if your service is going to do any CPU intensive work or blocking operations (such as MP3 playback or networking), you should create a new thread within the service to do that work. By using a separate thread, you will reduce the risk of Application Not Responding (ANR) errors and the application's main thread can remain dedicated to user interaction with your activities.

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

You should do it by an IntentService, for example. Or adding Handlers / Threads on that service.

Comment: THis dores not answer why the whole phone blocks.

Comment: I will try it and see if something will change